# How to add Api_KEY into interceptor using okhttp

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, interceptor, okhttp

I have this service where I want to put the token as an interception in the okhttp instead of passing as a parameter with @Header("MY_API_KEY")

This is my code regarding the service

```
/**
     * Provides the [PHService]
     */
    fun provideService(): PHService {

        val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logger.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC



        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logger)
                .build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(PHService::class.java)
    }
```

How can I add an interceptor for header authorization in here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**add like this**

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            // Request customization: add request headers
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", "MY_API_KEY"); // <-- this is the important line

            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });


    httpClient.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(logging);

 OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
```

**in kotlin its like**

```
 val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

    val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    httpClient.addInterceptor { chain ->
        val original = chain.request()

        // Request customization: add request headers
        val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "MY_API_KEY") // <-- this is the important line

        val request = requestBuilder.build()
        chain.proceed(request)
    }


    httpClient.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    httpClient.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(logging)

 val okHttpClient=httpClient.build()
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you wish to add an api_key and an app_id in your requests as a query parameter using retrofit and OkHttp interceptors in kotlin. You can follow the following steps. This is useful so you dont have to pass the keys in every request in each query:

```
const val E_BASE_URL = "https://api.example.com"
const val API_ID = "YourApiID"
const val API_KEY = "YourApiKey"

//Here you add your url interceptor
//"app_id" and "app_key" might be different, depending on your API
val api_interceptor = Interceptor {
        val originalRequest = it.request()
        val newHttpUrl = originalRequest.url.newBuilder()
            .addQueryParameter("app_id", API_ID)  
            .addQueryParameter("app_key", API_KEY)
            .build()
        val newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
            .url(newHttpUrl)
            .build()
        it.proceed(newRequest)
    }
    
//Add the logger interceptor optional:
val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply { setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC) }

//Build your OkHttpClient - here you add the api_interceptor and logger
val clientHTTP = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .addNetworkInterceptor(logger)  //optional
    .addNetworkInterceptor(api_interceptor)
    .build()

//Build your json converter - in this example MOSHI
val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()


//FINALLY build your retrofit 
val retrofitE = Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(clientHTTP)
    .baseUrl(E_BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .build()


//You can now declare your interfaces with your REST methods as usual, for example GET which will return your object
interface RecipesService {
    @GET("search")
    suspend fun getRecipes(
        @Query("q") recipe: String,
    ): RecipeResponse
}

//Finally you create your object (Singleton in Java) which generates your service via lazy delegate
object RecipesAPI {
    val retrofitService: RecipesService by lazy {
        retrofitE.create(RecipesService::class.java)
    }
}
```

For this example, you need to import following dependencies in the latest version:

```
com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit
com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin
com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi
com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor
```