# Retrofit2 : Adding token authorization as cookie header

Tags: android, cookies, http-headers, retrofit, okhttp

A simple API call is to be made using Retrofit to obtain the data. A cookie header is to be sent along with the request to authorise the request. 
The cookie has to be of the form,
token:

However, the authorisation is failing and hence the following exception is thrown at the execution -

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to <url>/xy.xyz.xyz.xy (port xyz) from /xy.x.xy.xy (port xx) after 10000ms`
```

A way to send a cookie header is to be found, so that the request is accepted by the server.

Here is what I have already tried,
Add a OkHttpClient and to it the required cookie header. Another thing I have tried is to add an additional parameter where retrofit method of type @Header. But there has been same problem in all these methods. And the API is tried and tested on postman also, and is working well.

Here is the code,

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    StudentObjectClass studentObject = new StudentObjectClass();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://<>/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
        Call<StudentObjectClass> call = retrofitInterface.getAttendanceData(730); //,"token=***; path=/api/; domain=.<>;");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<StudentObjectClass>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<StudentObjectClass> call, Response<StudentObjectClass> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Log.d("Tag","Server Error.");
                    return;
                }

                StudentObjectClass DataList = response.body();

                Log.e("Tag","The message is - "+ DataList.getMessage());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<StudentObjectClass> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Failed to fetch");
                Log.d("Tag",t.toString());             
            }
        });
    }
}
```

RetrofitInterface.java

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {

 @Headers("Cookie: token=****; path=/***/; domain=.<>")
    @GET("api/attendance?for=AllClassAttendance")
    Call<StudentObjectClass> getAttendanceData(@Query("student_id")int student_id);
}
```

StudentObjectClass.java

```
public class StudentObjectClass {

    public class Attendance{
        public String className;
        public int totalLectures;
        public int present;
        public int sick;
        public int absent;
        public int late;

        public int getAbsent() {
            return absent;
        }

        public int getPresent() {
            return present;
        }

        public int getSick() {
            return sick;
        }

        public int getLate() {
            return late;
        }

        public int getTotalLectures() {
            return totalLectures;
        }

        public String getClassName() {
            return className;
        }
    }

    public String message;

    public List<Attendance> attendance;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public List<Attendance> getAttendance() {
        return attendance;
    }

}
```

Additionally, the JSON data is of the form

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "attendance": [
        {
            "className": "xxx",
            "totalLectures": x,
            "present": x,
            "sick": x,
            "absent": x,
            "late": x
        },
        {
            "className": "xx",
            "totalLectures": x,
            "present": x,
            "sick": x,
            "absent": x,
            "late": x
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: this already answered. please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51833497/6559031

Comment: @Devil10 I have already tried adding an OkHttpClient to Retrofit and an interceptor to client, but it is giving same error

Comment: its socket timeout exception, you are not able to connect to the host within time limits. Thatswhy your request gets canceled without even reaching the host server.

Comment: @Devil10 But it might also be that the authentication is not set up properly, and hence this error. Anyway to increase the time so that I can check if token is properly inserted or not?

Comment: if its a token error then must be "unauthorized access" not socket timeout